# IntelliJ Git Java Project run

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I'm new at IntelliJ, and I can't run my Project (imported from git) as a Java project.
(I think) I installed JDK correctly. I tried "invalidate caches" also.

Some screens:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: I included the links into the question, you can delete your comment now.

Comment: @xXfreshXx, what is your Git repository link? Your program can't work, because it has wrong Java program folder structure.

Comment: the git repo is provided by my university. the folder structure is self made. i only wanted to test if it works via intelliJ and git so i only want to run a System.out.println. Later there should be a maven project in folder "Assignment 3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Assignment 3` directory as a `sources root` directory. Right click the `Assignment 3` directory and select `Mark Directory as` and then `Sources root` from the menu. The `Mark directory as` option is near the bottom.

That should tell IntelliJ that this directory has your src code in it.
[image: Mark Directory as screenshot]